# Using javascript to get values from radio buttons

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I'm attempting to setup a small web app using Flask and MySQL which takes information from radio buttons on a page and sends it into a DB.  I am very new to webdev, so I'm still stuck on actually getting the information from the buttons.

This is the HTML for my radio buttons (stripped of indents):

```
<div>
<input id="radioB" type="radio" name="radios" value="b" checked="checked">
<label for="radioB"><span><span></span></span>B</label>
</div>
<div>
<input id="radioT" type="radio" name="radios" value="t">
<label for="radioT"><span><span></span></span>T</label>
</div>
```

And this is my script:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/submit',
                    data: $('radios:checked').val(),
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                    }
            });
    });
});
```

and in my flask code, I am attempting to request it using:

```
_info = request.form['radios']
```

When I currently try to run this, I get a

```
"POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

error in the flask log, leading me to believe my problem lies either in the 'data' portion of my script and/or the flask request.  Any help with any portion of this would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I have changed my html to:

```
    <form action ="/submit" form method="post">
    <div>
        <input id="radioB" type="radio" name="radios" value="b" checked="checked">
        <label for="radioB"><span><span></span></span>B</label>
     </div>
     <div>
         <input id="radioT" type="radio" name="radios" value="t">
         <label for="radioT"><span><span></span></span>T</label>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
```

and my JS script to:

```
$(function(){
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
        var radioValue = $("input[name=radios]:checked").val();
        alert(radioValue);
        $.ajax({
                url: '/submit',
                data: {value:radioValue},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

and now am getting the error condition of the above JS script in the browser console instead of my previous error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$("input[name='radios']:checked").val();` to get radio button value i hope you get solution

```js
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name=radios]:checked").val();
            alert(radioValue);
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/submit',
                    data: {value:radioValue},
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                    }
            });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<div>
<input id="radioB" type="radio" name="radios" value="b" checked="checked">
<label for="radioB"><span><span></span></span>B</label>
</div>
<div>
<input id="radioT" type="radio" name="radios" value="t">
<label for="radioT"><span><span></span></span>T</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit">
</form>
```

Comment: I deleted the existing button i was using to submit and took your method.  I had to add <form action = "/submit" form method="post"> in addition to your form method post (submit is my flask function page) but it appears to be working somewhat. It appears my javascript script is not working as intended and returning the error condition.

Comment: Hey re-try my code i hope now u can find your problem easily and solve it.

in AJAX default request data type is JSON so you need to pass data in json format other wise you need to specify the dataType.
`$.ajax({
                    url: '/submit',
                    data: {value:radioValue},
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                    }
            });`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your assistance! The alert is giving me the correct values from the radios but I still am receiving the error condition in my browser console from the script.
"Object {readyState: 0, status: 0, statusText: "error"}"

Comment: My function is getting the value of the radio correctly so I don't care about the remaining issue, thank you again so much for the solution!

Comment: I am trying to use this code. But in app.py I get an error when I try to get the value of the radio button. I tried using `request.form['radios']` .

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be

```
$("input[name='radios']:checked").val()
```

if you are accessing with name!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes thank you, I believe you are correct but I am still getting an HTTP 400 error